# NuGet InvalidOperationException error while installing package

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am not able to install any package by Nuget.

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'AdDuplexWindows 8.0.5'. You are trying to      install this package into a project that targets 
>   'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or    content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more 
>   information, contact the package author.
>
> ```
> At line:1 char:1
> + Install-Package AdDuplexWindows
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
> ```

Comment: Could it be that none of the packages you've tried to install support Windows Phone 8?

Comment: We got InvalidOperationException and it seemed to be related to a failed package download - a DLL which was empty in packages. We deleted it and reinstalled and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are developing on Windows Phone 8 and you are trying to install adduplex with this command: (Install-Package AdDuplexWindows).
In this case the correct command is:

PM> Install-Package AdDuplexWP8